# R - Alluvial plots for combinations

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have been wondering how one could generate an alluvial plot using a data frame in R (e.g. utilizing `ggalluvial` package)

I have a data frame like following

```
   GENE UNTREATED TREATED
1    G1      FOUR    FOUR
2    G2      FOUR    FOUR
3    G3      FOUR    FOUR
4    G4      FOUR   THREE
5    G5     THREE    NONE
6    G6     THREE    NONE
7    G7       TWO   THREE
8    G8       TWO     ONE
9    G9       ONE     ONE
10  G10       TWO     ONE
```

I would like to generate an alluvial plot with this data. For example, 2 bars in the plot will be UNTREATED and TREATED and connections will be based on the proportions of how genes changing their values before and after treatment. It should definitely possible to do this and I didn't seem to get the grasp of alluvial plot concept. Any help would be highly appreciated.

EDIT: Here is a sample sketch I made how the plot would look like

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I should've added an image. I added now. I checked the link but I didn't really understand how to transform my data into the format of ggalluvial input.

Comment: try checking this [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggalluvial/vignettes/ggalluvial.html) for info on how to use `ggalluvial` if you are still having trouble please provide the code that you have tried so we can try to point out where you went wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be what you are after

```
dd<-read.table(text="   GENE UNTREATED TREATED
1    G1      FOUR    FOUR
2    G2      FOUR    FOUR
3    G3      FOUR    FOUR
4    G4      FOUR   THREE
5    G5     THREE    NONE
6    G6     THREE    NONE
7    G7       TWO   THREE
8    G8       TWO     ONE
9    G9       ONE     ONE
10  G10       TWO     ONE", header=TRUE)

ggplot(dd, aes(axis1=UNTREATED, axis2=TREATED)) +
  geom_alluvium() + 
  geom_stratum(width = 1/12, fill = "black", color = "grey") +
  geom_label(stat = "stratum", label.strata = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Woah, that's exactly how I wanted to plot. Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can use the `ggalluvial` wrappers that come with `easyalluvial`

```
 dd<-read.table(text="   GENE UNTREATED TREATED
               1    G1      FOUR    FOUR
               2    G2      FOUR    FOUR
               3    G3      FOUR    FOUR
               4    G4      FOUR   THREE
               5    G5     THREE    NONE
               6    G6     THREE    NONE
               7    G7       TWO   THREE
               8    G8       TWO     ONE
               9    G9       ONE     ONE
               10  G10       TWO     ONE", header=TRUE)


easyalluvial::alluvial_wide( dd, id = GENE, fill_by = 'all_flows',
                             order_levels = c('NONE','FOUR', 'THREE', 'TWO', 'ONE'))
```

[image: easyalluvial plot]

Answer (score 1):

MrFlick answer is very nice. Another option would be using alluvial plots, which has been discussed in "https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/755".

```
library(alluvial)
plotCM <- function(cm){
  cmdf <- as.data.frame(cm[["table"]])
  cmdf[["color"]] <- ifelse(cmdf[[1]] == cmdf[[2]], "green", "red")  
  alluvial::alluvial(cmdf[,1:2]
                 , freq = cmdf$Freq
                 , col = cmdf[["color"]]
                 , alpha = 0.5
                 , hide  = cmdf$Freq == 0
 )
}

dd<-read.table(text="   GENE UNTREATED TREATED
1    G1      FOUR    FOUR
2    G2      FOUR    FOUR
3    G3      FOUR    FOUR
4    G4      FOUR   THREE
5    G5     THREE    NONE
6    G6     THREE    NONE
7    G7       TWO   THREE
8    G8       TWO     ONE
9    G9       ONE     ONE
10  G10       TWO     ONE", header=TRUE)

labels=unique(dd$UNTREATED)
d1 <- factor(dd$UNTREATED,labels=labels)
d2 <- factor(dd$TREATED,labels=labels)
confusionMatrix(d1,d2) %>% plotCM()
```

[image]

Hope it helps.

Thanks, Sam